# atof() is not taking entire value in symbian

Tags: c, char, symbian, printf

when i try to convert char to float i am using atof and it's not returning entire value,& **how to correct this** *Is there any other method to do this?*

If i give value of this length(700.898) its returning correct value. If I give more than 3 numbers then only facing problem.Sorry if i am asking any thing wrong.

```
float flt = 71237.898;
char myfloat[50];
sprintf (myfloat, "%f", flt);  //myfloat = 71 237.8984380
float f = atof(myfloat); //f = 71.0000
```

to remove spaces:

```
int myfllen = strlen(myfloat);
    for(int b=0;b<strlen(myfloat);b++)
        {
        if(myfloat[b] == ' ')
            {
            int c = b;
            while(c<=myfllen)
                {
                myfloat[c] = myfloat[c+1]; 
                c++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: can yopu post the case in which you are getting problem?

Comment: he did post the case... the code is what hes finding an issue with

Comment: @DanZimm that code is working fine http://codepad.org/z77DEjq9

Comment: Is this a trick question? I'm wondering if the person who gave OP this problem intentionally omitted header files (so that `atof` would be treated as implicitly returning `int`) and setup the value so that on OP's system, when interpreting the result as `int`, it comes out as 71. Adding the comment with a space for a thousands separator could be part of the trick...

Comment: when float is implicity returned as int then it will not give 71 for 71237.898 but it will give some other large value...

Comment: @R.. in that case argument to the atof() will also be implicity converted into int?

Comment: @Mr.32: On most cpu archs/ABIs, floating point and integer return values travel in different registers. Thus it's not a matter of a value getting reinterpreted, but rather what happens to end up in the integer-return-value register when `atof` is done with this input.

Comment: And no, arguments are not implicitly converted to `int`. They're subject to default promotions.

Comment: @20120: Did you actually run the code? And if you did, then did you actually have that space in the string produced by `sprintf`?

Comment: @ AndreyT: yes i had run the code then only i posted this ques with the values at the right side of code.yes i have space in myfloat value i can see like this in debug mode [0]= '7',[1]= '1',[2]= ' ',[3]= '2'.....that's why atof is not returning corrct value.

Comment: @20120: OK, so can you try including `<locale.h>` and doing `setlocale` as I suggested before? I'm just curious if it will help...

Comment: Sounds like symbian's libc is just badly broken...

Answer (score 4):

Do you really have that space between `71` and `237` after `sprintf`, as you posted in the comments? If so, then this is most likely what makes `atof` stop parsing the string after `71`. You can actually switch to `strtod` (always a much better idea than `atof`) and ask it to give you the character position that caused it to stop parsing.

Apparently your locale settings make `sprintf` use space as digit group separator. Meanwhile `atof` is not locale-aware. The language specification does not require `atof` (`strtod`) to recognize locale-specific number formats for locales other than `"C"` locale.

Do `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C")` before `sprintf` and it should hopefully get rid of that space. Or clean out those spaces manually.

Comment: guessing sprintf might be doing that? otherwise no idea

Comment: yes that's correct but i am not giving any spaces in that value. how to avoid spaces with sprintf??

Comment: @20120: As I said above, switch to `"C"` locale before doing `sprintf`. C programs are actually supposed to start in `"C"` locale. Is there a chance that someone intentionally changes the current locale setting in your program? If so, you might have to save and restore the original locale.

Comment: Thousands separators are **not** permitted in the output of `sprintf`, regardless of locale, unless a special format specifier is used to request it. This `sprintf` implementation is dangerously non-conformant.

Comment: In carbide c i think i cant use LC_ALL getting undefined identifier LC_ALL. there's no other option other than to remove spaces manually.

Comment: @20120: You need to include `<locale.h>` first to use `setlocale` and `LC_ALL`.

Comment: @AndreyT  I copied this line setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"); before sprintf but still spaces's there. i need to do anything else??

Comment: @20120: Well, that's just... crazy. The standard library seems to be working incorrectly. If so, the only way out would be to remove those spaces manually, i.e. write a function that will "compress" the string by removing the inner spaces.

Comment: @AndreyT I have written these lines and its working if anyhthing wrong please correct me. code added above

Answer (score 0):

i have used your code and make small program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
double flt = 71237.898;
char myfloat[50];
sprintf (myfloat, "%f", flt);  
double f = atof(myfloat); 
printf("answer is %f",f);
return 0;
}
```

which gives output of

```
answer is 71237.898000
```

see http://codepad.org/GMWScwqK

**i think you get problem because of using float as return value .... but in real atof returns double value...**

Comment: No, that's not the problem. The `double` value returned by `atof()` will be implicitly converted to `float`, and will keep the same value (with some loss of precision).